# How to use a Poller with a timer to kick off SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have a sequence container with a sequence of execute package jobs. I want those jobs to execute every 10min. is there a way to insert poller that executes the sequence container every 10min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean solution would be to schedule the task inside of sql server agent to run every 10 minutes.

If you do not have this option, you can add a script task that will poll every x seconds, however this is not ideal

Depending on your scenario, this may be useful [make-an-ssis-package-delay-or-wait-for-data](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MikeDavis/ssis/158/make-an-ssis-package-delay-or-wait-for-data)